# How do I parse this IDA-generated asm file to get a list of mnemonics for each function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, assembly, ida

I have asm file, that was produced with IDA Pro. All of its functions looks almost like this.

```
; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================


release                                 ; DATA XREF: attribute_manager_create+78↓o
                                        ; attribute_manager_create+7C↓o ...

var_30          = -0x30
var_24          = -0x24
arg_0           =  0
arg_4           =  4

                PUSH    {R4-R9,LR}
                MOV     R7, R0
                LDR     R0, [R0,#0x34]
                SUB     SP, SP, #0x14
                MOV     R9, R3
                LDR     R3, [R0]
                MOV     R5, R1
                MOV     R8, R2
                BLX     R3
                LDR     R0, [R7,#0x30]
                ADD     R6, SP, #0x30+var_24
                LDR     R3, [R0,#4]
                BLX     R3
                MOV     R4, R0
                B       loc_7A7C
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

loc_7A70                                ; CODE XREF: release+5C↓j
                LDR     R3, [SP,#0x30+var_24]
                CMP     R3, R5
                BEQ     loc_7AB4

loc_7A7C                                ; CODE XREF: release+38↑j
                LDR     R3, [R4]
                MOV     R1, R6
                MOV     R0, R4
                BLX     R3
                CMP     R0, #0
                BNE     loc_7A70

loc_7A94                                ; CODE XREF: release+A0↓j
                LDR     R3, [R4,#8]
                MOV     R0, R4
                BLX     R3
                LDR     R0, [R7,#0x34]
                LDR     R3, [R0,#0xC]
                BLX     R3
                ADD     SP, SP, #0x14
                POP     {R4-R9,PC}
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

loc_7AB4                                ; CODE XREF: release+44↑j
                LDR     R3, [SP,#0x30+arg_4]
                STR     R3, [SP,#0x30+var_30]
                MOV     R2, R9
                LDR     R3, [SP,#0x30+arg_0]
                LDR     R6, [R5,#4]
                MOV     R1, R8
                MOV     R0, R5
                BLX     R6
                B       loc_7A94
; End of function release
```

I want to parse this file and get a dictionary where the key will be the name of the function and the value will be a string that is formed from the instructions combined together. I will explain in more detail.

I have a dictionary in which each Arm instruction corresponds to a specific letter.

```
arm_dict = {"MOV": "a","MVN": "b","ADD": "c","SUB": "d","MUL": "e","LSL": "f","LSR": "g","ASR": "h","ROR": "i","CMP": "j","AND": "k","ORR": "l","EOR": "m","LDR": "n","STR": "o","LDM": "p","STM": "q","PUSH": "r","POP": "s","B": "t","BL": "u","BLX": "v","BEQ": "w","SWI": "x","SVC": "y","NOP": "z"}
```

When parsing, you need the instruction to become this letter. For example, the above function in the dictionary should look like this:

```
{'release': 'randanaavncnvat...'}
```

If the code contains an instruction that is not in arm_dict, then that instruction is skipped.

I've tried to parse linearly using strings containing "S U B R O U T I N E" and "End of function", but I can't get rid of the instruction operands. I would be glad if someone can provide some sample code or advice.

Comment: It would be good if you add the code you have so far, even if it's not working

Comment: Try using `line.split(maxsplit=1)[0]` to remove operands, by not passing a delimiter to split it defaults to splitting on whitespace except preceeding whitespace which is ignored. `maxsplit` is the number of times the string will be split. By performing this split and return the first item, the first non-whitespace, whitespace delimited word will be returned.

Comment: @OnGle: Most real-world assembly syntaxes (including I think ARM assemblers that could assemble this) allow a label on the same line as an instruction mnemonic, like `loc_7A7C:  LDR     R3, [R4]`.  If you're just parsing disassembler output from one disassembler that doesn't do that, then sure, you can assume that if there's a mnemonic rather than a label, the mnemonic will be the first token on the line.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for this context peter. In this case, labels must first be separated. Assuming comments are already handled, a label might be extracted with `label,line = line.split(':', maxsplit=1)` this however requires you've already determined a label is present and I'm unsure if `:` appears in other places in any common asm grammers so I'm not sure how to easily test that.

Comment: @OnGle: It won't appear outside of (single or double) quoted strings, except to indicate labels.  So it can appear like `db "string with: punctuation"` or `mov r0, #':' // mov-immediate to register`.  Or in comments, after an `@` or `//`, or I guess `;` - ARMASM (unlike the GNU assembler) uses `;` as a comment character for ARM.   Anyway, `:` indicating a label should only appear right after the first token on a line, I think.  Possibly separated by whitespace; that would be ugly style but may syntactically be allowed.

Comment: @PeterCordes Given this number of caveats trying to get a robust solution it might well be worth using a proper parsing solution, `pyparsing` or `lark` might be good things to look into. But at risk of digging myself a deeper hole, regular expressions can bridge the gap here `match = re.match('\s*([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*):', line)` will return either a match object or `None` if not found. If found, the rest of the line will be equal to `line[match.end():]` and the label equal to `match.group(1)`

Comment: You have an IDA pro, right? If you use IDAPython, you can get instruction mnemonics by using `ida_ua.ua_mnem()`.

Comment: @OnGle: Thinking about this some more, the lack of any decoration on label names is odd, and would lead to near ambiguity if you had a function called `add`.  Some assembly syntaxes have labels start in column 0, so label vs. mnemonic is a matter of leading whitespace.  So e.g. you could have `add     add r0, r1`.   Whether that's required or not for ARMASM to assemble it, that seems to be what IDA is doing so it's a simple way to distinguish label from mnemonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
arm_dict = {"MOV": "a","MVN": "b","ADD": "c","SUB": "d","MUL": "e","LSL": "f","LSR": "g","ASR": "h","ROR": "i","CMP": "j","AND": "k","ORR": "l","EOR": "m","LDR": "n","STR": "o","LDM": "p","STM": "q","PUSH": "r","POP": "s","B": "t","BL": "u","BLX": "v","BEQ": "w","SWI": "x","SVC": "y","NOP": "z"}
FILE_NAME = "ida_output.asm"
result = ""

with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split()
        # if the line is empty, skip it
        if not words:
            continue
        if words[0] in arm_dict:
            result += arm_dict[words[0]]

print(result)
```

Heres a messy edited version after peter's suggestion:

```py
arm_dict = {"MOV": "a","MVN": "b","ADD": "c","SUB": "d","MUL": "e","LSL": "f","LSR": "g","ASR": "h","ROR": "i","CMP": "j","AND": "k","ORR": "l","EOR": "m","LDR": "n","STR": "o","LDM": "p","STM": "q","PUSH": "r","POP": "s","B": "t","BL": "u","BLX": "v","BEQ": "w","SWI": "x","SVC": "y","NOP": "z"}
FILE_NAME = "ida_output.asm"

def trim(line):
    if ";" in line:
        return line.split(";")[0]
    return line

functions = {}
with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
    label = None
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        words = line.split()
        # if the line is empty, skip it
        if not words:
            continue
        first = words[0]
        if label and first in arm_dict:
            functions[label] += arm_dict[first]
        elif first[0] != ";" and (not label or (not line[0].isspace() and "=" not in trim(line) and label not in line)):
            label = first
            functions[label] = ""



print(functions)
```

Theres lots of potential edge cases it could fail, but it should do pretty alright.

Comment: This misses detecting `release` as the start of a function (`loc_[[::hex:]]+` labels as local within functions and should be ignored).  But sure, looks reasonable for output from this disassembler, which never puts a label on the same line as a mnemonic.  But it could maybe be fooled if you had a function label that happened to match a mnemonic, e.g. a function called `add`, because you don't check for the first token starting in column 0 or not (leading whitespace disambiguates label from instruction mnemonic in some syntaxes, probably including this one given the lack of `:` after them.)

Comment: @PeterCordes ah i see. I missed that. I'll add that in my code right now